# how to post in user's Streams using google plus api in java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus, scribe

I want to share some information in google plus wall from my application.and I am trying for moment.insert, But getting 400 error . Can somebody help me

```
@Override
  public JSONObject getGooglePlusAddUseractivities(Object token) {
  Token accessToken = (Token) token;
  OAuthService service = createOAuthServiceForGooglePlus();
   OAuthRequest request = new       OAuthRequest(Method.POST,"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault");
   request.addQuerystringParameter("alt", "json");
   service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
   JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
   try {
     object.put("kind","plus#moment");
     object.put("type","http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"); 
     JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();
     obj1.put("kind", "plus#itemScope");
     obj1.put("url","https://plus.google.com/me");
     obj1.put("description","Sign up now to claim and redeem your credits while          shopping! ");
     obj1.put("image","http://invite.png");
     obj1.put("contentUrl", "www.abcd.com");
     obj1.put("thumbnailUrl", "http://logo1_favicon.png");
     object.putOpt("target", obj1);;
     }catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     request.addPayload(object.toString());
     request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     System.out.println("request : "+request.getBodyContents());
     Response response = request.send();
     String responseBody = response.getBody();
     JSONObject googleJSON = null;
     try {
      googleJSON = new JSONObject(responseBody);
     }
     catch (JSONException e) {
      System.out.println("can not create JSON Object");
     }
```

getting 400 error ??  anyone can tell me..... where am wrong ..!!`

Answer (score 4):

It isn't clear from the documentation, but you can't provide both the `target.url` and most other `target` metadata. This is currently opened as [bug 485](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=485) in the issue tracking system - please go there and star the issue to make sure they properly prioritize a fix.

If you remove the `target.url` value and add a `target.id` value, it should work.

(As an aside, this does not post in the user's stream, but will post an App Activity in their app moment vault. They must manually share the activity if they choose.)

Comment: thnx Prisoner. i have fixed up with this also private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity&access_type=offline";   i hvn't mentioned request_visible_actions in authorization url. now code is working but not posting on user's stream. Can u help me?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying at this point. Sounds like it might be best to start another question.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, it is not possible to programmatically write to a user's Stream. As a developer, you have two options:

1. Write an AppActivity (formerly known as a Moment), which writes information to Google, but not to a Google+ Stream. These activities are visible at plus.google.com/apps, and will be used by Google in additional ways over time.
2. Create an Interactive Post Share button, which a user must initiate. However, you can pre-fill both the text of the post and up to 10 intended recipients. The user can make changes if they want and then perform the actual share. You can learn more at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive or by watching this Google+ Developers Live episode: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Iw28jWtAY.